# NoNodeAvailableException : None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to search from Elastic Search within my Java Web Service,
here's how I use now :

```
    Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.10.150"), 9200));
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
```

The 1st line could work without an error, but when it goes to the 2nd line, the exception down below will occur :

> NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available:
>   [{#transport#-1}{TskPSVeBRR6CvCzP9EVhkQ}{192.168.10.150}{192.168.10.150:9200}]]

No matter I use **9200** or **9300** to set the **port**, the results are the same.

Also, I've tried to search from my **.Net** program using **NEST**, and it run just fine. Here's how I tried :

```
    var node = new Uri("http://192.168.10.150:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("iod-2017.03.08.*");
    _EsClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
    var index = String.Format("iod-{0}.{1:00}.{2:00}.*", item.TriggerTime.Year, item.TriggerTime.Month, item.TriggerTime.Day);
    var uniqueId = item.UniqueId.ToString();
    var result = _EsClient.Search<logs>(s => s.Index(index).Query(q => q.Match(t => t.Field(l => l.id).Query(uniqueId))));
```

Did I do anything(**Firewall**, **version** of library, **method** to call the API, etc) wrong with my Java program? My current **Java** version is **1.8.0.121**, the version of **Elastic Search** and **Transport Client** are both **5.2**. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check whether you can telnet to the ES box on port 9300 from your local box ? 9200 seems to be open as it is being used by your .NET client

Comment: Are you using a cluster name other than elasticsearch ? If yes, have you updated the same in settings ?

Comment: I've solve my problem! You're right, I should use 9300 port, but the critical error is that I didn't set the cluster name correctly. I can search after I set cluster.name in Settings. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad, it solved your problem. Have added the same in an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in comments,

If you are using a cluster name other than `elasticsearch`, then you need to update the same in settings.

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, my cluster name & everything were correct, but my elastic cluster was using X-Pack Security. And it was only because of that.

Here is solutions - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/java-clients.html

Answer (score 0):

From documentation,

```
// on startup

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are install elasticsearch from extracted file (e.g.: elasticsearch-5.4.0.tar.gz), please try to install it in through yum or other RPM tool. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html 
It help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the program make sure you ran the **elasticSearch.bat** batch file present under **ElasticSearch -> config folder**. Also make sure you see *"started"* logged in the console where you ran the batch file.

You can check if elastic search started successfully or not by hitting the URL [localhost:9200](http://localhost:9200). You should see a page looking something like this:

```
{
  "name" : ...,
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : ...,
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.2",
    ...
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the cluster name as a parameter on the connection URI:

1. Go to `http://<elasticsearch_host>:9200`
2. Retrieve the `cluster_name` value and add it as a parameter to the connection URI:
   `elasticsearch://<elasticsearch_host>:9300?cluster.name=<cluster_name_value>`

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is pointing to elasticSearch transport client is not able to establish a connection with elasticsearch server.

Root cause might be the port name or IP/hostname of server OR cluster Name OR **Authentication** is incorrect.

Open elasticSearch.yaml file and validate all details correctly.
To ignore clusterName validation by using the following configuration params.

```
client.transport.ignore_cluster_name = true
```

Full code snippet to create transport Client is:

```
 Settings settingsBuilder = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", DBPropertyUtil.getPropertyByName("es.cluster")).put("client.transport.sniff", true).put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true).build();
            //.put("client.transport.sniff", true).put("path.home", ".").build();
         Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settingsBuilder)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
```

Specify host and port as per your server. This code is working fine for me.